# Keeping two fields of a type "in-sync"? Foo<X> (x:X implies y: Y)

Tags: typescript

I am wondering how to get two types to "correlate"? As in the following example, I only want to allow `TypeContent` to be of a type that makes sense for the type T.

```
export type DataReport<T extends Type, TypeContent> = {
  id: number
  createdAtDateTime: Iso8601DateTime
  contentType: T
  content: TypeContent // should depend on T somehow
}
```

If I could have used a javascript map, it would be something like

```
TypeMap = {
   Questionnaire: { id: string, items: QuestionnaireItem[] }
   BloodSample:  { dueDate: Iso8601DateTime }
}

const TypeContent = TypeMap[Type] // Type = BloodSample or Questionnaire
```

Is this possible to express in Typescript somehow?

Comment: What is `Type`? What is `Iso8601DateTime`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N9EpoN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a type map the same, using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

```js
type TypeMap = {
  Questionnaire: { id: string, items: QuestionnaireItem[] }
  BloodSample:  { dueDate: Iso8601DateTime }
}

type Types = keyof TypeMap

export type DataReport<T extends Types> = {
  id: number
  createdAtDateTime: Iso8601DateTime
  contentType: T
  content: TypeMap[T]
}

type Test = DataReport<'Questionnaire'>
// => 
{
    id: number;
    createdAtDateTime: Iso8601DateTime;
    contentType: "Questionnaire";
    content: {
        id: string;
        items: QuestionnaireItem[];
    };
}
```

See this on [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2aEVW)